# Use some of tables without prefix in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am merging my database with magento and specifying prefix 'edu_' for my tables of laravel. I need to set relationship with customer table of magento i.e. customer_entity.

```
Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('comment');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('last_modified_by')->unsigned();
        $table->string('ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('entity_id')->on('customer_entity');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

While specifying relation ship, I get error because Laravel treats customer_entity as edu_customer_entity.

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `edu_article_comments` add constraint article_com  
  ments_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `edu_customer_entity` (`entity_id`))
```

Is there any way to solve the issue ???

Comment: Can you post your schema for two tables, migrations & other staffs.

Comment: I am not creating customer_entity table from migrations. As it is already available. All other tables I am creating by  migrations.Modified schema for article_Comments migration table.

Answer (score 0):

Add the migration in two steps:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('comment');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('last_modified_by')->unsigned();
        $table->string('ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

 Schema::table('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('entity_id')->on('customer_entity');
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** 
If you wanna create a relationship with a table that already exists, create one more migration file in the end to specify all the relationships.

For example:

```
Schema::table('table', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('column')->references('column')->on('table')->onDelete('action');

    Schema::table('areas', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('column')->references('column')->on('tablename')->onDelete('action');
    });
```

Comment: I cant use Schema::create two times as it will create table again which will throw error and if i use schema::table , again i will get the sane error.

Answer (score 0):

Add `DB::raw()` method into `on()` relationship method. Like this:

```
Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('comment');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('last_modified_by')->unsigned();
        $table->string('ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('entity_id')->on(DB::raw('customer_entity'));
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```